# Is there a way to show the "To" address in the Gmail inbox?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have an email wildcard `*.example.com` set up for my private domain so that all messages, regardless of the prefix will be forwarded to my Gmail account.

I use this so I can give different email addresses to different people and companies without needing to set them up individually.

My question is, in Gmail, is there any way to display the specific "To" address without first having to open the email?

For example, is there something that can add a label that matches the "To" address or alternatively  show the "To" column in the inbox?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the columns that are displayed in Gmail but you can add a label to incoming messages based on the `TO` address.

### Filter Based on `TO`  Address

1. Create a filter based on the address you want to apply a label to. The simplest way is probably to start with a search, such as:

   ```
   to:address1@example.com
   ```
2. Next, press the down-pointing arrow to the right of the search field to open the advanced search form and then click **"Create a filter with this search"**.
3. On the next window, click **"Apply the label:"** and choose the label you want to use (or create a new one).
4. Select any other things you might want to happen.
5. Optionally, to label messages already received, check **"Also apply filter to matching conversations"**
6. Save the filter.

Now, when a message comes in addressed to `address1@example.com` the filter will apply your  label.

### Notes

1. You can also include messages where the address is included on the `CC` and/or `BCC` fields. For example:

   ```
   to:address1@example.com OR cc:address1@example.com OR bcc:address1@example.com
   ```

   or the equivalent

   ```
   {to:address1@example.com cc:address1@example.com bcc:address1@example.com}
   ```
2. You will need a separate filter for each address that needs a unique label, however you can use a single filter for multiple addresses that share a common label. For example:

   ```
   to:({address1@example.com address2@example.com address@example.com})
   ```
3. You can create a single filter for all prefixes from the same domain by leaving out the prefix from the search. For example:*

   ```
   to:example.com
   ```
4. If you need to create many filters, you can save time by doing it in a text editor.

   1. Create the first filter.
   2. Export your filter(s)
   3. Edit the XML file to add additional filters using the first filter as an example/template.
   4. Import the edited XML file back into Gmail.

### Gmail Resources

- [Create rules to filter your emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579)
- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

---

* credit to [@JPvdB](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/232791) for pointing out the wildcard aporoach

Comment: But this means I have to specify one for EVERY email address I want to use, correct?

Comment: If you want to use the same label for multiple addresses, you can use `to:address1@gmail.com OR to:address2@gmail.com OR to:address3@gmail.com`. If you want one label per address, then yes, you need a separate filter for each.

Comment: You could save time by creating one such filter, exporting your filters, editing the export file (it's just XML) to create more filters, then re-importing it.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is I want this added dynamically. I dont want to have to add a list of email addresses as it will be ever growing.

Comment: Then what you're looking to do won't be possible with just Gmail alone. You'd need some other tool.

Comment: If you want to create a filter for all items that are from the wild card you can create a filter like this:
From: @example.com
That sets a label to the mail. Then all wildcards (1@example.com, 2@example.com etc) will get that label.